# How to make variable act like reference in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you have "ByRef" arguments in AS3 functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335624/can-you-have-byref-arguments-in-as3-functions)

Primitive types in AS3 pass by value instead of reference. Is there a way to override that behavior and pass by reference for certain variables? Take the following code:

```
for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<4; j++) {
        if(i==0 && j==0){
            switch(currentRotation){

            case 0:
                var1 = j; //I want var 1 to be a reference to j, not the value of j
                    break;

            }
        }
        if(someArray[var1][var2]){
            //stuff
        }
    }
}
```

If this isn't possible, I guess I'll just have to copy and paste the code a few times. :/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may cheat a bit. Wrap `j` into some object:

```
var obj = {j: 0};
for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
    while (obj.j < 4) {
        if(i==0 && obj.j==0){
            switch(currentRotation){

            case 0:
                //...
                    break;

            }
        }
        if(someArray[var1][var2]){
            //stuff
        }
        obj.j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh! Never thought of that. Thanks!

Comment: +1 Good solution but, curious where is the "obj.j++"

Comment: @The_asMan,thank you! I missed it)

Answer (score 1):

No, primitive types could only be passed by value.

Answer (score 1):

Primitive types in AS3 are actually passed by reference but they are immutable so behave as if they were passed by values.

> For readers interested in the technical details, ActionScript stores primitive values internally as immutable objects. The fact that they are stored as immutable objects means that passing by reference is effectively the same as passing by value. This cuts down on memory usage and increases execution speed, because references are usually significantly smaller than the values themselves.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9c.html

And so you wont be able to override this behaviour.